# Autofill shipping fields for local pickup

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'm looking for a way to automatically input a simple message "Customer to pick up." in the shipping section when a customer chooses local pickup as the shipping method on my WooCommerce site. It could be in the street address field, just as long as it shows up in the order email.

I'm new to php and not getting even close to a solution with any of the code I've hacked together.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care to show the change live, during the checkout, you can try something like this. Comments inline on the code

```
//we trigger this code when the order has been placed 
//and the user is redirected to the thank you page
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'pickup_text_on_shipping', 10, 1 );

function pickup_text_on_shipping( $order_id ) {

    //if something went wrong and we don't have an order id, don't do anything
    if ( ! $order_id ) return;

    //this is the id of the shipping method we want to run the code
    $shipping_method = 1; // change this to the correct id

    //get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    //get the shipping methods and run our updates only if the specific
    //method was selected
    foreach($order->get_shipping_methods() as $shipping_item ){
        

        if( $shipping_item->get_method_id() == $shipping_method ){
        
            //we update the shipping address field with the custom text
            //you want to show on the email
            update_post_meta( $order->ID, '_shipping_address_1', 'Customer to pick up.');
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately. I've set up a fresh development site with two products, and default free shipping and local pickup. I see that when local pickup is selected the "Shipping address" table is completely eliminated from the order email. When I perform this with free shipping the shipping table column shows up in the email but without the custom message. Btw, this is the id format I'm using in your code: $shipping_method = 'shipping_method_0_free_shipping1';